# Hide page when second click on menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jQuery to display an accordion menu when clicking on a menu title.

The first click displays the corresponding details page, and it works fine. Now, I need to hide this details page when the user clicks on that link for the second time.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use toggle jquery for that, refer below link.

http://chandreshmaheshwari.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/show-hide-div-content-using-jquery/

This may helpful to you

Thanks.